# Getting error on gatsby build command: TypeError: Unexpected response from worker: undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, gatsby

I am getting this error when I run the command `$ gatsby build` on the terminal.

What gets my attention on this one is that it mentions `jest-worker`, and I don't see that module on my package.json. I see it only in the `node_modules` folder.

I already tried many things. Deleting `node_modules`, `package_lock.json`, `npm cache clean --force` and some other things.

I can't find these errors on the internet either.

If I keep scrolling down on the terminal, the error ends with this:

```
/Users/marcelo/Work/SM/gatsby-on-demand/node_modules/yoga-layout-prebuilt/yoga-layout/build/Release/nbind.js:53
        throw ex;
        ^

Error: write EPIPE
    at process.target._send (internal/child_process.js:806:20)
    at process.target.send (internal/child_process.js:676:19)
    at /Users/marcelo/Work/SM/gatsby-on-demand/node_modules/gatsby-cli/lib/reporter/loggers/ipc/index.js:58:13
    at dispatch (/Users/marcelo/Work/SM/gatsby-on-demand/node_modules/gatsby-cli/lib/reporter/redux/index.js:54:5)
    at Object.createLog (/Users/marcelo/Work/SM/gatsby-on-demand/node_modules/redux/lib/redux.js:483:12)
    at Reporter.log (/Users/marcelo/Work/SM/gatsby-on-demand/node_modules/gatsby-cli/lib/reporter/reporter.js:173:40)
    at Object.console.log (/Users/marcelo/Work/SM/gatsby-on-demand/node_modules/gatsby-cli/lib/reporter/patch-console.js:17:14)
    at WithHeaderLayout (/Users/marcelo/Work/SM/gatsby-on-demand/public/render-page.js:104712:376)
    at d (/Users/marcelo/Work/SM/gatsby-on-demand/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:36:498)
    at $a (/Users/marcelo/Work/SM/gatsby-on-demand/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:39:16)
    at a.b.render (/Users/marcelo/Work/SM/gatsby-on-demand/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:44:476)
    at a.b.read (/Users/marcelo/Work/SM/gatsby-on-demand/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:44:18)
    at renderToString (/Users/marcelo/Work/SM/gatsby-on-demand/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:54:364)
    at Module.default (/Users/marcelo/Work/SM/gatsby-on-demand/public/render-page.js:710:28)
    at /Users/marcelo/Work/SM/gatsby-on-demand/node_modules/gatsby/dist/utils/worker/render-html.js:28:36
    at Promise._execute (/Users/marcelo/Work/SM/gatsby-on-demand/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/debuggability.js:384:9)
Emitted 'error' event on process instance at:
    at processEmit [as emit] (/Users/marcelo/Work/SM/gatsby-on-demand/node_modules/signal-exit/index.js:161:32)
    at internal/child_process.js:810:39
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11) {
  errno: 'EPIPE',
  code: 'EPIPE',
  syscall: 'write'
}
```

I've been going through this the whole day.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Can you provide your package.json? To check your dependencies and its versions